# query get records lesser than SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion, inner-join

This query which get records of all clubs, i check record per records. The NULL columns doesn't play any role. Howerver i filled NULL's. This mean any NULL isn't existing.
This query get 202 recordcount using cfquery and on MSSQL 2014 get 204 records.

Could you please tell what could happen that cfquery can't get some records. The exact query work on MSSQL 2014 perfectly.

```
    SELECT tblDistrict.IDDist, 
           tblClubs.IDDiv,
           tblClubs.ClubArtStart, 
           tblClubs.IDClub, 
           tblClubs.ClubName, 
           tblDivisionen.DivBezeichnung, 
           tblDivisionen.Region, 
           tblClubs.OrgDatum, 
           tblClubs.ChartDatum, 
           tblClubs.ClubStatus, 
           tblClubs.ClubArt,   
           tblClubs.Clubort

    FROM  (tblDistrict 
                INNER JOIN tblDivisionen ON tblDistrict.IDDist = tblDivisionen.IDDist)

            INNER JOIN tblClubs ON tblDivisionen.IDDiv = tblClubs.IDDiv

            WHERE (((tblDistrict.IDDist)=1)) AND Clubstatus<>'E' AND Clubstatus<>'I'
```

Comment: Are you asking why rows with Clubstatus null are not picked up? Not sure to understand your question

Comment: use the profiler to see what exact command is send to your database. Maybe it is a bit different then you expect

Comment: why is the main table and the first join inside brackets ?

Comment: @MiloBellano i ask the query is exactly same. but output using cfquery is 202 and on MSSQL is 204 records

Comment: how do you know the query is exact the same ? have you checked with a profiler ? If not then you do not know fur sure they are the same

Comment: Without a LOT more detail here there is little anybody can do but speculate.

Comment: What are you looking at that tells you the record count for the two places from which you run this query?

Comment: If you're using the exact same query within a cfquery, then you should be getting the exact same results as in MSSQL (as long as the datasources are the same). It might be different is if the `datasource` in the cfquery is different from the source selected in MSSQL.

Comment: Are you using query caching? It could be that you are getting a cached version of the data from cfquery.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with some formatting and aliasing. Your query would look something like this. This would be a lot more maintainable.

```
SELECT d.IDDist
    , c.IDDiv
    , c.ClubArtStart
    , c.IDClub
    , c.ClubName
    , div.DivBezeichnung
    , div.Region
    , c.OrgDatum
    , c.ChartDatum
    , c.ClubStatus
    , c.ClubArt
    , c.Clubort
FROM tblDistrict d
INNER JOIN tblDivisionen div ON d.IDDist = div.IDDist
INNER JOIN tblClubs c ON div.IDDiv = c.IDDiv
WHERE d.IDDist = 1 
    AND c.Clubstatus not in ('E', 'I')
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `c.Clubstatus not in ('E','I')`? Just wondering.

Comment: @WEI_DBA just didn't fix that part. :)

Comment: In his query the OP has the maintable and the first join inside brackets. Does that makes any difference in sql server ?

Comment: @GuidoG It shouldn't. I believe SQL Server's optimizer unwinds all of the parentheses in this case.